# sqlalchemy dbapi How to transfer args to cursor?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector-python

https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py

```python
  def create_cursor(self):
        if self._use_server_side_cursor():
            self._is_server_side = True
            return self.create_server_side_cursor()
        else:
            self._is_server_side = False
            return self._dbapi_connection.cursor()
```

the mysql connector 
connection.py

```python
def cursor(self, buffered=None, raw=None, prepared=None, cursor_class=None,
           dictionary=None, named_tuple=None):
```

I want to used the prepared=True

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py


# unfortunately, MySQL/connector python refuses to release a

        # cursor without reading fully, so non-buffered isn't an option

        opts.setdefault('buffered', True)  #force...